# Wear OS animation Android

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-wear-2.0, watch-face-api

How can i animate a `line` on a canvas in `WearOS` every 5 seconds?

I know that we have to use an AnimatorTask with a call to `postInvalidate()`. However since I am directly drawing the `line` on the `canvas`, I do not have a `View` object.

```
public class AnimatorTask extends TimerTask {

    private WatchEventInfo eventInfo;

    public AnimatorTask(WatchEventInfo eventInfo) {
        this.eventInfo = eventInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        drawAndAnimate();
    }

    public WatchEventInfo getEventInfo() {
        return eventInfo;
    }

    private void drawAndAnimate() {

        Canvas canvas = eventInfo.getCanvas();

        // For testing
        canvas.drawLine(100, 100, 300, 300 markerPaint);
    }
}
```

How do get access to the `canvas.drawLine()` method object and notify the `canvas` to redraw itself from the `TimerTask` assuming that my `TimerTask` exists in `CanvasWatchFaceService` subclass?

Answer (score 2):

You get access to the canvas by overriding the `onDraw(Canvas canvas, Rect bounds)` method declared in the CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine class.

If you create your watch face using the New Project wizard in Android Studio, you'll notice a method at the end of the MyWatchFace class called `handleUpdateTimeMessage()`. This logic will ensure that your onDraw method gets called at the interval specified by `INTERACTIVE_UPDATE_RATE_MS` (default is once per second) in interactive mode.

Add a check in your onDraw method to only trigger your line animation if five seconds have past since the last update.